# Powershell Error while creating specific Folder in Library!

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create nested folders in a library based on an input.
Below is my code. This works for all other values except few. I am not getting what wrong I do. It works for values less than 50 characters but not above it. But if I create a folder manually, it gets created through UI.

```
# Creating the Log File
$Logfile = ".\Log-Success-$(get-date -format MMddyyHHmmss)-list.csv"

Function LogWrite
{
    Param ([string]$logstring)
    Add-content $Logfile -value $logstring
}

# Importing Partner Name list in CSV
$documentlib =Import-Csv -Path ".\PartnerFolderName.csv"

# site collection URL
$webUrl = "http://someurl/rec/site1" 
$web = Get-SPWeb $webUrl   

# Input Name of New Record Type through Console        
$folderNamePrefix = Read-host â€œEnter the new Value â€; # here i input the value "the value is always this big in thes feild"

# Check whether Record Type name has only Alphanumeric characters with spaces and Hyphen included
if ($folderNamePrefix -match '^[\da-zA-Z -]+$')
{

    Write-Host $folderNamePrefix " is a Valid Value"

    # Fetching Each Partner name from CSV to Create Folder
    foreach($lib in $documentlib)
    {
        $list = $web.Lists[$lib.DocumentLibrary]

        # Creating One subfolder within the folder

         $subFolderURL=$webUrl+"/"+$lib.DocumentLibrary+"/folder1/folder2"    # Location to create New Folder
        try
        {

            $folder = $list.AddItem($subFolderURL, [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileSystemObjectType]::Folder, $folderNamePrefix)
            $folder.Update()

            $SuccessMSG=$lib.DocumentLibrary +",The Folder structure for " +$folderNamePrefix +" is Created Successfully."
            LogWrite $SuccessMSG

        }

        # If an Error is Encountered
        catch
        {
            $errormessage = $_.Exception.Message
            $MSG =$lib.DocumentLibrary +","+$errormessage
            LogWrite $MSG
        }
    }
}
# If value is Invalid and contains special characters
Else
{
    Write-Host $folderNamePrefix  " contains Special Charecters that are restricted"
}

$web.Dispose()
$documentlib =$null
$folderNamePrefix =$null
$folder=$null
$list=$null
$FolderPath=$null
```

Comment: It would help if you could post the error message

Comment: Are you sure there is no issue with the total path length as you mention an issue past 50 characters of name(you are allowed a maximum of 260 characters), some more details would allow us to assist better :)